# SQL Server - divide by zero error in WHERE clause (even with condition divisor > 0)

Tags: sql, sql-server, divide-by-zero

I have encountered a seemingly strange error when testing an SQL query with `WHERE` clause involving division. Task is to find errors in invoice where **any** of the following is true:

- Either `Amount` or `Tax` is zero (not both);
- Both `Amount` and `Tax` are not zero, but they don't meet certain arithmetic condition.

So the query I came up with is as follows:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Amount, Tax
FROM Invoices
    WHERE (Amount <> 0 AND Tax = 0)
    OR (Amount = 0 AND Tax <> 0)
    OR (Amount <> 0 AND Tax <> 0 AND ABS(Tax / Amount - 0.18) > 0.005)
```

To make things more strange, this query works okay:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Amount, Tax
FROM Invoices
    WHERE Amount <> 0 AND Tax <> 0 AND ABS(Tax / Amount - 0.18) > 0.005
```

I guess that Boolean evaluation in SQL Server conditional clauses does not work as in C# (where I could expect lazy evaluation preventing division by zero error).

How do I make this query correct?

***NOTE:*** There are tens of millions of records, so nested `SELECT` statements may affect performance.

Comment: `Amount <> 0.18` ?

Comment: Probably just put proper brackets around expressions to make sure that you are not making an error in judging operator precedence.

Comment: @Cid won't it do the division first, maybe it also needs `ABS(Tax / (Amount - 0.18))`.

Comment: @SteveSmith it's supposed to do, indeed, but who knows if priority is well respected?

Comment: SQL *explicitly* does not define an evaluation order between predicates. You may have some luck putting your "guard" predicate in a `WHEN` clause and the "guarded" predicate in the `THEN` clause of a `CASE` expression, but even that is not 100% reliable.

Comment: `NULLIF(Amount, 0)`. Division by 0 isn't allowed, but division by `NULL` is. As you've discovered, it's essentially impossible to force the optimizer to not evaluate the expression. Even `CASE` doesn't always work.

Comment: The formula is correct (division, then subtraction). The brackets, even put explicitly everywhere to ensure precedence, still produce error. While the second query runs okay. I guess SQL server is forming subsets of records based on comparison before running arithmetic condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not depend on order of evaluation of clauses or conditions in a query.  Period.  *The optimizer reserves the right to rearrange everything for performance.*  Okay, not everything.  `CASE` expressions have a guaranteed order of evaluation.

The solution is quite simple.  Use `NULLIF()`:

```
WHERE (Amount <> 0 AND Tax = 0) OR
      (Amount = 0 AND Tax <> 0) OR
      (Amount <> 0 AND Tax <> 0 AND ABS(Tax / NULLIF(Amount, 0) - 0.18) > 0.005)

WHERE Amount <> 0 AND Tax <> 0 AND ABS(Tax / NULLIF(Amount, 0) - 0.18) > 0.005
```

Comment: Re: `CASE` expressions - except for aggregates and expressions therein which *may* be evaluated even when not required.

Comment: I used to be a `CASE` believer like you, then I took a bad execution plan to the... cache. Bug reports about `CASE` not doing shortcut evaluation under some specific circumstances have been consistently closed (or ignored) as "working as designed" / "won't fix" / "but it's faster this way, usually".

Answer (score -1):

did you try using parenthesis

```
 SELECT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, Amount, Tax
FROM Invoices
    WHERE (Amount <> 0 AND Tax = 0)
    OR (Amount = 0 AND Tax <> 0)
    OR (Amount <> 0 AND Tax <> 0 AND ABS(Tax / Amount - 0.18) > 0.005)
```

When dealing with multiple conditions (Or/And) try to separate then by using "()".

The logical order of operators is

- Arithmetic
- Concatenation
- Comparison conditions
- IS [NOT] NULL, LIKE, [NOT] IN
- [NOT] BETWEEN
- Not equal to
- NOT
- AND
- OR

You can use parentheses handle this rules.

Comment: brackets control how the operators are interpreted but they *do not* control evaluation order (certainly in ANSI SQL and SQL Server. Other products may offer some guarantees).

Comment: Sorry, this is definitely not the case. I put all the excessive brackets to ensure operator precedence, but still have div/0 error.

Comment: Yes, that's the *logical order*. But SQL Server is perfectly happy to *evaluate* predicates in a different order (provided it combines the results correctly according to the logical order) and even produce errors because it has eagerly evaluated a predicate it would not need to if it *did* follow the logical order *and* implemented short circuiting behaviour (neither of which it does guarantee, neither of which are required to conform to the SQL Standard)

Comment: Try to check documentation on SQL SERVER parentheses and logical order, i think you will find it very useful  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: See the other answer. The problem here was not in query syntax, but in dealing with unobvious SQL Server execution optimization.

Comment: The optimizer doesn't care about logical order. It will happily evaluate subexpressions at any time it deems convenient, even if these subexpression later turn out to be logically superfluous. This logical order dictates the *parsed semantics* of the expression, *not* the order subexpressions are evaluated in (or whether they're evaluated at all). Subexpressions should be well-formed under all possible conditions, or else you're going to get bitten -- logical order or no.